# .gt operator in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a master_reference object that corresponds to a file in a Pandas data frame with four columns of metrics.

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1000., 1001., 2000., 3000.], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
    'two' : pd.Series([1000., 1001., 2000., 3000.], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
    'three' : pd.Series([1000., 1001., 2000., 3000.], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
    'four' : pd.Series([1000., 1001., 2000., 3000.], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])}
master_reference = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Also, I have an interesting_list of indices that I wish to find one (or more) "twins" from the master_reference.

```
interesting_list = ['A','B','C']
```

To accomplish this I have located the indices and associated metrics.

```
retrieve = master_reference.ix[interesting_list]
```

Using a dict comprehension, I iterate through the master_reference to a given tolerance, say 5%.  No matches and multiple matches would be fine.

```
matches = {twin_id: master_reference[(master_reference.div(retrieve.ix[twin_id].values) - 1)
        .abs()
        .lt(0.05)
        .gt(0) #why wont this work???
        .all(axis=1)].index.tolist()
    for twin_id in retrieve.index}
print matches
```

Here is my output dict:

```
{'A': ['A', 'B'], 'C': ['C'], 'B': ['A', 'B']}
```

Given my 5% tolerance, using the .lt operator, A and B are twins.  But you can see that each letter also found itself, which is why the .gt operator is there to make sure the difference between two values is greater than 0.  It should eliminate the problem of including itself in the results.  According to the [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html?highlight=gt#pandas.DataFrame.gt) do I need another argument here? Is there a simpler operator I am not thinking of whereby the list object and its corresponding index can avoid each other altogether?  I'm using Python 2.7 on OS 10.10.5.  Thanks for any insight.  This community is such a great resource.

Here is some updated code using .applymap:

```
tolerance = .05
def window(x):
    if x > 0 and x <= tolerance:
        return x
matches = {twin_id: master_reference[(master_reference.div(retrieve.ix[twin_id].values) - 1)
        .abs()
        .applymap(window)
        .all(axis=1)].index.tolist()
    for twin_id in retrieve.index}
print matches
```

Why does my new output look like this?  There is something simple that I missed!

```
{'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'C': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
```

Comment: After calling `.lt(0.05)`, the result will be a boolean Series, so you're now calling `.gt(0)` on `True, False` values rather than your original numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing yourself by the way you are chaining the operations there.  The result of applying a boolean operation like `lt` is a series containing True or False at every position: True if the value satisfies the condition, false otherwise.  Since True in Python is the same as the number one, in something like `.lt(0.05).gt(0)`, the `gt(0)` is a no-op.  The `lt` gives True for all the values that are greater than 0.05, and True is greater than 0 (because True==1), so the `gt` doesn't filter anything.

You will either have to duplicate the first part of your expression to do

```
master_reference.div(retrieve.ix[twin_id].values) - 1).abs().lt(0.05) & master_reference.div(retrieve.ix[twin_id].values) - 1).abs().gt(0)
```

Or, instead of using `lt` and `gt` use `apply` to apply a function that does all your filtering at once.

Comment: I was unaware of the bitwise nature of the '&' sign.  Thanks for the explanation!.

Comment: .applymap(lambda x: x <= tolerance and x > 0)